# Найти в слове апостроф и заменить на двойную

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть процедура, которая обновляет записи,  есть входящий параметр `@email`.

Проблема: в некоторых ситуациях в значение параметра передаются email адреса c апострофом, а sql как знаете не понимает данные значении.

Примеры такие:  `@email = 'Aiza'Mar' ,  Al'Saad`

Как, если в начале в слове есть апостроф, найти заменить на двойные апострофы?

Comment: Функция translate?

Comment: *а sql как знаете не понимает данные значении* Всё он прекрасно понимает - если передавать значение как параметр, а не вставлять в текст запроса конкатенацией.

Comment: TRANSLATE() - это из пушки по воробьям, к тому же она не умеет заменять один символ на два, что правильнее для квотирования, нежели замена простой кавычки на двойную (такая замена необратима, ибо может при обратной замене сделать значение email невалидным). [REPLACE()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions167.htm#SQLRF00697) более чем достаточно, и менять надо на `''` либо `\'`.

Comment: Замену апострофов можно выполнить с помощью *регулярного выражения* (https://www.sql.ru/blogs/oracleandsql/1372). Подбирать выражение удобно, например, на этом сайте https://regexr.com/